# My container is Warning BackOff or Crashloopback

Tags: azure, kubernetes, yaml, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I am creating several microservices on Azure (Kubernetes) and I have the following problem: if I do not put this command inside the YAML container it shows the message of BackOff or CrashloopBack and does not leave there.

The command I place is this:

```
    command: [ "sleep" ]
    args: [ "infinity" ]
```

This is the error that shows if I do not put this code

```
Warning BackOff 7s (x4 over 37s) kubelet, aks-agentpool-29153703-2 Back-off restarting the failed container
```

My DockerFile for one of this microservices:

```
FROM node:10 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY package.json /app 
RUN npm install 
COPY . /app 
CMD npm start EXPOSE 6060
```

My YAML:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: permis-deployment
  labels:
    app: permis-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: permis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: permis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: permis
        image: myacr.azurecr.io/permission-container:latest
        command: [ "sleep" ]
        args: [ "infinity" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6060

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: permis-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: permis
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6060
      targetPort: 6060
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong or what is wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you building the Docker image and pushing at `myacr.azurecr.io/permission-container:latest` before you deploy the YAML?

Comment: Yes, first I create the image, then the container and finally upload it to the ACR. Once in ACR I do the apply -f yamlfile.yaml

Comment: Why is the container exiting?  (For example, what does `kubectl logs` on the CrashLoopBackOff pod say?)

Comment: When I do the Kubectl Logs does not throw any information, with the Kubectl describe pod "namepod"  I have information, but I can't copy it here if you tell me what might interest me tell me and I try to copy in some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is running fine, change the `Dockerfile` by this one and re-create the image. Should work:

```
FROM node:10 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY package.json /app 
RUN npm install 
COPY . /app 
EXPOSE 6060

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you do the following:

```
containers:
- args:
  - -ec
  - sleep 1000
command:
  - /bin/sh
```

invoking `sleep` directly didnt work for me

Comment: spec:
      containers:
      - name: permis
        image: myacr.azurecr.io/permission-container:latest
      - args:
        - -ec
        - sleep 1000
      command: ["/bin/sh"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6060

It's correct?

Comment: so, there should be an app running, it doesn't, and you are suggesting to run `sleep` to make the container up? with what purpose?

Comment: If I do not place the argument mentioned above, the container does not remain runnin

Comment: i dont know what the OP is trying to accomplish, in his question he attempts to run pod indefinitely with a `sleep` command, I'm showing him how to accomplish that